# FInd all instances a name repeats and add Scores of each one

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have people being rated 1-10 (1-7=Bad & 9-10=Good) when I look at the report it gives all the ratings but it does not filter by person being rated.

What I want is a formula that will find All the instances the name on `Sheet2 Cell A1` appears in the `Sheet1 A:A`, then match those instances with the score besides each one on `column B`

[image]

In the cells here, such formula would return me the following information:

```
"Essia"  on column B (Good Scores) = 1 | on column C (Bad Scores) = 0
"Jesse" on column B (Good Scores) = 2 | on column C (Bad Scores) = 0
"Ben" on column B (Good Scores) = 2 | on column C (Bad Scores) = 0
```

I know this has to include some kind of `=IF(_____ <8,+1` or something like that?

All I know is this:
Sheet that contains the data is `Sheet1`
It contains an infinite display of names (multiple repeats for each) on `column A` and on column b (besides each instance) the score that that person got at that time,

Sheet where I need the results is `Sheet2`
I want to have a list of all people being rated (one instance for each) and excel to see the name on each cell in `column A` and give me how many "Good Scores"( 9-10) that person has (based on the data in `Sheet1`) in `Column B` and then the same but for "Bad Scores"(0-7) on `Column C`.

Right now I have the following formula but it only gives me the amount of times that an associate was rated not how many of those are "Good" and how many are "Bad"

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A2)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNTIFS`:

To count good scores:

```
B2:
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!B:B, ">7")
```

and bad scores:

```
C2:
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A2, Sheet1!B:B, "<=7")
```

These are formulas for row 2; copy and paste down to autofill all the rows in sheet2.